# Formatting List of Text Strings in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to turn the font to red for the occurrences of a list of words in excel. So far, I am able to find a single word, but I need to search for a whole array. I am a newbie with VBA and struggling. So far, I've been able to find this as a solution, but it deals with finding a single string, "F1":

```
Sub test4String2color()
Dim strTest As String
Dim strLen As Integer
strTest = Range("F1")
For Each cell In Range("A1:D100")
If InStr(cell, strTest) > 0 Then
cell.Characters(InStr(cell, strTest), strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Edit:

The cells I need highlighted have the items listed in comma separated format. For example, "Apple 1, Apple 3, Banana 4, Orange". The list of values to search from are in Different cells, "Apple", "Banana 4". I only want to highlight "Banana 4" because this is an EXACT match with the comma separated values. In the current formulation, the text that says "Apple 1" or "Apple 4" would be partially highlighted.

Edit 2:

[image: Examples]

This is the actual format from my workbook:

[image: Example 3]

Comment: "...but I need to search for a whole array", what do you mean? If I put `Gotham` in `F1`, it correctly highlights any finding of `Gotham` in the range `A1:D100` (it highlights "Gotham" and all text after in the cell). Are you saying that `F1` could have, say `Gotham, City, Wayne Enterprises`, and you want to search for each one of those words (separated by a comma, or some other delimiter)?

Comment: You're on the right track. You could make `strTest` a Collection and cycle through it for matches with a second `For Loop`. Since you're not using any UDTs, a collection would be easy to setup and loop through.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm saying I'd want to search for Gotham, City, Wayne Enterprises. But they would all be in separate cells, not in a single cell separated by commas. I have a list of about 200 words, each in a different cell that I want to use as my search terms.

Comment: Could you instead perhaps just use text to columns, using a comma delimiter, then just maybe use conditional formatting? Or do you need VBA? (You'd need to combine the red words together but it may be an alternative)

Comment: I tried it originally, but because of the size of the data set and the range of items in each cell (some have 2 while some have 50), the text to column option started to get very messy and difficult to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a method to achieve what you desire by looping through a range, collection, and array.**

The code will find matches between the collection (your chosen match words) and the array (the string of words delimited in each cell). If a match is found, the starting and ending characters in the string are set and the characters between those values are colored.

```
Sub ColorMatchingString()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim strTest As Collection: Set strTest = New Collection
    Dim udRange As Range: Set udRange = ws.Range("AC2:AC311") 'Define Search Ranges
    Dim myCell, myMatch, myString, i
    Dim temp() As String, tempLength As Integer, stringLength As Integer
    Dim startLength as Integer

    For Each myMatch In udRange 'Build the collection with Search Range Values
        strTest.Add myMatch.Value
    Next myMatch

    For Each myCell In ws.Range("A2:AB1125") 'Loop through each cell in range
        temp() = Split(myCell.Text, ", ") 'define our temp array as "," delimited
        startLength = 0
        stringLength = 0

        For i = 0 To UBound(temp) 'Loop through each item in temp array
            tempLength = Len(temp(i))
            stringLength = stringLength + tempLength + 2

            For Each myString In strTest
  'Below compares the temp array value to the collection value. If matched, color red.
                If StrComp(temp(i), myString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
                    startLength = stringLength - tempLength - 1
                    myCell.Characters(startLength, tempLength).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Next myString
        Next i
        Erase temp 'Always clear your array when it's defined in a loop
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! This works great. But one more level of complexity I initially overlooked. The cells I need highlighted have the items listed in comma separated format. For example, "Apple 1, Banana 3, Banana, Orange 4". The list of values to search from are in Different cells, "Apple", "Orange", "Apple 1", "Banana 3". I only want to highlight "Apple 1" and "Banana 3" because these are EXACT matches with the comma separated values.

Comment: Not super clear on my comment. This may make more sense: The cells I need highlighted have the items listed in comma separated format. For example, "Apple 1, Apple 3, Banana 4, Orange". The list of values to search from are in Different cells, "Apple", "Banana 4". I only want to highlight "Banana 4" because this is an EXACT match with the comma separated values. In the current formulation, the text that says "Apple 1" or "Apple 4" would be partially highlighted. "

Comment: @user6883405 I've updated my code to do what you want it to. Check that the results are as you expect... wait nvm. This will go for any iteration of your string, gimme a little longer..

Comment: @user6883405 I finally figured it out! That was a lot of fun, I gotta tell you. This will perform exactly as you described in your question. If I didn't understand something, or this performs otherwise, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! This works when I test it out with sample data, but not with my actual data set. Originally, semicolon was the delimiter and each item in a single cell was on a new line. I went through and replaced all semicolons with commas. When I run the code, it only words for single cell instances. I'll share an image.

Comment: I recall when I experimented with text to columns with this data set I use something else besides semicolon. I think an ASCII character? Potentially carriage return, but I don't know that this would return a semicolon.

Comment: The text to column works with the alt +J, and keeps a semicolon between each term, so I am thinking the ascii character is (13), carriage return and has a semicolon with no space after

Comment: @user6883405 So by setting the delimiter to `CHR(13)` you were able to port it to your code and make it work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work yet. I edited the code to:                     temp() = Split(myCell.Text, Chr(13))                                                      But that has proved unsuccessful @Tyeler

Comment: Just now looked at your picture, it's not `Chr(13)`. Try setting the delimiter to the following: `"," & Chr(10)`. You only need 1 character as the delimiter, so if you're going to have line breaks in your cells, you could use `Chr(10)` as the delimiter, or do both with the comma included. Totally up to you. :D

Comment: @user6883405 FYI: If you choose to only use `Chr(10)` as the delimiter, remove all of the commas from the string so you only have word>line break>word>line break>etc.

Comment: Success!!! This is my first experience using VBA, and I can see why it's such a useful tool.

Comment: @user6883405 For a first experience with VBA, you sure picked a tricky problem! Now you have the hard choice of choosing who's answer solved your question best (for you). Thanks for giving us the opportunity to help you!

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with your original code, you can just add another `For each cell in Range` (and a few other things):

```
Sub test4String2color()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim strLen  As Integer
Dim i       As Long
Dim tst As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Dim keyWordRng As Range
Dim dataRng As Range
Set keyWordRng = ws.Range("F1:F2")
Set dataRng = ws.Range("A1:A5")

For Each tst In keyWordRng
    Debug.Print "Searching for: " & tst
    For Each cell In dataRng
        If tst.Value = cell.Value Then
            cell.Characters(InStr(cell, tst), strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf InStr(1, cell.Value, ",") > 0 Then
            getWordsInCell cell, tst.Value
        End If
    Next cell
Next tst
End Sub


Sub getWordsInCell(ByVal cel As Range, keyword As String)
Dim words() As String
Dim keywordS As Integer, keywordE As Integer
words = Split(cel.Value, ",")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
    Debug.Print "Found multiple words - one of them is: " & words(i)
    If Trim(words(i)) = keyword Then
        keywordS = ActiveWorkbook.WorksheetFunction.Search(keyword, cel, 1)
        keywordE = ActiveWorkbook.WorksheetFunction.Search(",", cel, keywordS)
        cel.Characters(keywordS, (keywordE - keywordS)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Please note I added to ranges (`keyWordRng` and `dataRng`) which you will need to tweak for your sheet. This should (fingers crossed) work!

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a method to only highlight exact matches? The cells I need highlighted have the items listed in comma separated format. For example, "Apple 1, Apple 3, Banana 4, Orange". The list of values to search from are in Different cells, "Apple", "Banana 4". I only want to highlight "Banana 4" because this is an EXACT match with the comma separated values. In the current formulation, the text that says "Apple 1" or "Apple 4" would be partially highlighted.

Comment: @user6883405 - See the updated code (it's just the `If ` line was updated).  From what I gather, your range `F1:H1` (for example) has a single "keyword" in each cell, such as `Banana`, `Banana 4`, `Apple`.  Your range `A1:D100` has a bunch of words in a single cell, such as `Banana 4, Apple, Cars`. You **only** want the cells highlighted where the *entire cell* matches your keyword?  So it'd highlight cell `C4` if that cell is *only* `Banana 4`?

Comment: Almost! I'd want the portion of the cells highlighted that have an exact match. So in your example Banana 4 and Apple would be highlighted. However, if it said Banana 5 instead, I would not want just the Banana part highlighted. I'd only want it highlighted if it an exact match between the comma separated value. @BruceWayne

Comment: @user6883405 - I appreciate your description, but would you mind creating a sample table of what you want, and post a screenshot? I think I see, but a visual would help.  (Doesn't have to be 100 rows obviously, but say 3 keywords, and how you expect them to be highlighted)

Comment: Of course! I edited my original post. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: In your example, I'd also want the "Apple" text in cell A7 highlighted. I've added another image for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: @user6883405 - Ah, okay. I think I got it. Check the edit.

Comment: @BruceWayne You beat me to it again! I was trying to turn each cell into an array, compare them with the match words, and then return them formatted to their cell, but I couldn't quite figure out how to specify the formatting. Solid code you made!

Comment: @Tyeler - Thanks, nice code as well to you!  This turned into a fun little exercise...I had to think too as to how to get the coloring done.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a "Run-Time Error '1004': Unable to get the Search property of the WorksheetFunction class. Then it highlights code row "keywordE = WorksheetFunction.Search(",", cel, keywordS)".

Comment: @user6883405 - Argh! When that happens, the line above it ran okay? (`keywordS = ...`)??  Is there a chance you changed workbooks/sheets during the macro?

Comment: @BruceWayne Not sure if the line above it ran okay, but no formatting changes are made to the workbook. Only one sheet/workbook up.

Comment: @user6883405 - That's odd, hm.  I edited the code to include explicit references to your activebook/activesheet. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: @BruceWayne Strange, it's giving me the the same error but "438" instead of "1004" and it higlights the row above the one it did last time.

Comment: @user6883405 - ! Hm, I'll take a look tomorrow. In the meantime, I *think* it's how we passed through the range? I suggest just googling like "VBA error 438 worksheetfunction" or like "VBA error 438 worksheetfunction search", etc...

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks Bruce!! I'll look.

Comment: @user6883405 - For a quick test, in the first `Sub`, add this: `If WorksheetFunction.Search("1", Range("A1"), 1) > 0 Then Debug.Print "works"` right after `Set dataRng` line.  Also, in cell `A1`, put the number `1`. It shouldn't throw an error. If it doesn't, we can narrow the issue to that second Sub. If it does, it's something else...

Comment: @BruceWayne I got the same error. I modified the keyWordRng and dataRng though. Could that affect it? Set keyWordRng = ws.Range("AC2:AC311") and Set dataRng = ws.Range("A2:AB1125")

Comment: @user6883405 try replacing `ActiveWorkbook` with `Application`

Comment: @BruceWayne I finally solved the issues I was having with assigning the colors to the right segments of the string! That was some good puzzle fun.